# React Leaflet popups not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet in an application and it works as intended unless it is viewed from a mobile device (both physical and through dev tools). On mobile devices, the popups will appear and immediately disappear after about 0.2 seconds.

Some points to note

- if I refresh the page on a mobile device via chrome dev tools and then switch to the regular view then the issue persists.
- It appears as though two click events are being detected by the MapContainer when this issue occurs. One of these click events has `isTrusted: flase, _simulated: true`. I think this could be the route of the issue.
- When a popup is clicked it can be observed in devtools that the following div has a child which is immediately removed. `<div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div>`

Here is the issue replicated in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cloud-eqcco?file=/src/App.js).
If you click the button to pop out the browser window, switch it to view as a mobile device in dev tools, and then refresh the page, you can see what happens.

My component looks like this:

```
  export const MapView: React.FC<IMapViewProps> = ({
  ...
}) => {
 
  const Markers = data.map(({ location, name, id, events }) => (
    <Marker
      position={[location.lat, location.lon]}
      key={id}
      eventHandlers={{
        click: () => {
          console.log("clicked"); // THIS FIRES TWICE
        },
      }}
    >
      <Popup>
        <span>{name}</span>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  ));
    
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <br></br>
       IF I TAP HERE ONLY ONE CLICK EVENT IS RECORDED SO IT MUST BE IN THE MAPCONTAINER
        <br></br>
      </div>
      <MapContainer
        center={[55.9533, -3.1883]}
        zoom={10}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
        className={styles.container}
        doubleClickZoom
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {Markers}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I can provide any other information please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Can we get some more details:  What mobile devices are you testing on?  What browser are you running on that device?  What dev tools are you using to debug in the mobile environment?  Is this an emulated environment or a real mobile device that you've got hooked up to your app?

Comment: Not reproducible on React Leaflet demo https://react-leaflet.js.org/. You should provide a live reproduction example, e.g. using CodeSandbox or StackBlitz.

Comment: @SethLutske The issue happened on both firefox and chrome dev tools. It also occurred on Safari on an iPhone 12.

Comment: @ghybs Here is the issue replicated in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cloud-eqcco?file=/src/App.js). If you click the button to pop out the browser window, switch it to view as a mobile device in dev tools, and then refresh the page, you can see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Your CodeSandbox works fine for me (both embedded and standalone previews) on mobile Chrome 90 Android 8 and 10.

Comment: @ghybs thanks for checking so quickly. So you're going to CodeSandbox, clicking "open in new window", opening dev tools, and switching to a mobile view, then refreshing the page? If that works for you I'm very confused as to what my next steps are. If I open [this link to the page directly](https://eqcco.csb.app/) on a mobile device then the issue is still there.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue on iPhone 11 in safari with the standalone preview and the embedded viewer.  No issue on my laptop even with devtools in mobile mode.  Very interesting that @ghybs has no problem with chrome on android...

Comment: I only have actual physical mobile devices right now. I have not tried on desktop browser with mobile view.

Comment: I tried this sandbox on my laptop on safari, the popup doesn't even open.  Check out [***this issue***](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255) - this is a reported leaflet bug when using safari.

Comment: @SethLutske I had a look at that issue and adding tap={false} solved the problem. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @SethLutske pointed out this issue seems to stem from [leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255).

Adding `tap={false}` to the MapContainer seems to have solved this issue.

```
 <MapContainer
    center={[55.9533, -3.1883]}
    zoom={10}
    scrollWheelZoom={false}
    style={{ height: "100vh" }}
    className={styles.container}
    doubleClickZoom
    tap={false}
  >
     ...
  </MapContainer>
```